# Can infinitives replace gerunds after 'rather than'?

Tags: usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

I learned from grammar books that ***rather than*** can be used both as a conjunction and as a preposition.
So can ***live*** replace ***living*** in the following sentence (A) like (B)? I think it can according to the grammar rule, but I'm not quite sure.

> (A) Rather than living in a typical modern apartment, they can have a
>   living space that looks like a home from the 1970s or 80s.

**or**

> (B) Rather than live in a typical modern apartment, they can have a
>   living space that looks like a home from the 1970s or 80s.

Comment: Both sound fine to me, I actually like B more because it gets rid of the repetition of "living"

Comment: "Rather than" is never a preposition. It's either a case of "rather" being an adverb and "than" a preposition functioning as head of a comparative complement **or**, as in your examples, it's a compound coordinator with the comparative meaning 'in preference to', I'd say that (A) and (B) are equally fine

Comment: I personally prefer (this is stylistic and open to personal opinion) something different from either: *Rather than **live in a typical modern apartment**, they can*  ***live in a space that looks like a home from the 1970s or 80s.*** I don't like mixing *live* with *living* because it breaks the parallelism of the sentence, and I prefer the active *live* to the more passive *living*.

Comment: Parallelism is only an issue in coordination. The OP's examples are not coordinations but  comparative constructions

Answer (score 1):

If you used sentence A then I would probably assume that *they* are currently living in a typical modern apartment. I would be less likely to assume that if you used sentence B.

I have no idea if what I am saying is technically correct according to any rules of English. I offer my advice purely as a native speaker of British English. I have no formal qualifications in English and in fact don't even understand some of the words used in your question, so don't rely on what I say!